# How to rerender the complete dom-repeat in Polymer on a Array change

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I just started playing with Polymer and have been struggling to solve following issue.

In below code when the button is clicked `myItem` array is changed and parent template `dom-repeat` is rerendered, but the child template `dom-repeat` is not updated.

The reason might be the child dom-repeat is bound to the function `_get`.

```
  <dom-module id="my-element">
   <template>
    <button on-click="_removeLastTwo">switch</button>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myItem}}">
    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_get(item)}}">
       <li>{{item}}</li>
       </template>
     </ul> 
    </template>
   </template>
  </dom-module>


 <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
      data: {
        type: Array,
        value: [9,8]   
        },
      myItem:{
        type:Array,
        value:[1,2,3,4,5]
      } 
     },
     _get:function(t){
       var d = this.myItem.length;
       return [d+1,d+2]
     },
     _removeLastTwo: function(){
       this.myItem = [1,2]
     }
  });
 </script>
```

How can I overcome this issue, check it at http://jsbin.com/misuvehuwe/edit?html,output . Am I missing any basic approach??

Comment: prefer APIs like `this.set` or `this.push` instead of `this.myItems=[1,2]`